# Short sentence headlines text wrapping on mobile

Tags: content, header, ux-writing

Background:

I'm the only one at this company who has a UX background, and there are no content writers on staff who have experience in digital spheres. They are used to print media, which doesn't respond to various viewports.

Here's the issue:

Our content creators have a headline that consists of three short sentences, for example:
*"Be heard. Feel supported. Be well."*

Looks okay on desktop, but on mobile the statement wraps the second sentence, thus breaking that thought into two lines:

*"Feel

supported."*

[image]

I cannot seem to find any articles or sources to back up what I suspect is a readability/scanability issue. The marketing team will not rewrite unless there is research or directly sourced evidence to back up that this is in fact a UX issue.

What do you all think? And is there any source material on this issue?

Comment: this is a UX and readability issue, you can easily find this on Google and they teach this in the first year of any design university. But rather than documenting it, why don't you simply reduce the size of teh font and make everybody happy?

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the font size on mobile. Plenty of respectable articles out there that touch on this point.

One example:

[https://www.toptal.com/designers/typography/web-typography-infographic#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20best%20font,on%20a%20desktop%20computer%20screen](https://www.toptal.com/designers/typography/web-typography-infographic#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20best%20font,on%20a%20desktop%20computer%20screen).

If you expect to just change the viewport, and not adjust to the viewports boundary's items (text, borders, margins, paddings, etc), then you're failing at responsive design.

One thing you don't want to do, and your marketing team better respect this — because it's graphic design 101 for print material failures — is to not have "widows" or "orphans" in printed text. Example, in your screenshot above, "supported" would be a widow or an orphan.

Reduce the font size slightly in this case to solve the issue. Coming from 12 years of marketing and advertising, and then 20+ in web and software design, these are not decisions print designers get to make anymore. But are decisions they have to accept. Especially if they are not making a conscious effort to adapt to a responsive and mobile world (seriously, in 2023?).

This is where the rubber hits the road for the those that are not able to adjust and adapt, and those that know and unfortunately have to force them to.

As a web and mobile designer, you have to guide the folks that are stuck in their ways.

Good luck.